# Transition accounting for amount of content - currently expanding too much Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/wss2sbgo/6/

I've included the jsfiddle above to show what I mean.

Basically in the light blue box I have an abnormal amount of copy to illustrate that the bottom expands way down on hover. My question would be, is there another solution to this that wouldn't require this extra movement down below? Something that would be more side to side maybe or no extra movement. I'm thinking that because the difference in height of the divs this isn't the case, but thought I'd ask.

This is what I currently have

> HTML

```
<div class="stripe row" id="secondNav">
      <div class="secondNav-sidebars secondNav-columns-3">
              <div class="secondNav-sidebars-bg"></div>
              <div class="container hoverWidge hovered">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="secondNav-widgets secondNav-widgets-1 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="addPad">
                            <h3>Product Solutions</h3>
                              <p class="show">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<button class="btn btn-white">Learn More</button></p>
                             </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="secondNav-widgets secondNav-widgets-2 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                            <div class="addPad addPadNoLeft">
                            <h3>Nutrition</h3>
                             <p class="noShow">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..<button class="btn btn-white">Learn More</button></p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="secondNav-widgets secondNav-widgets-3 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                            <div class="addPad addPadNoLeft">
                            <h3>Capabilities</h3>
                             <p class="noShow">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..<button class="btn btn-white">Learn More</button></p>
                             </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

> Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.secondNav-widgets').hover(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('col-md-6')) {                                  

        }else {
        $(this).find(".noShow").switchClass( "noShow", "show", 500, "easeInSine" ).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
        $('.secondNav-widgets').find(".show").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).removeClass("show", 0).addClass("noShow", 0).css({display:"none"});
        });
        $('.secondNav-widgets').switchClass( "col-md-6", "col-md-3", 1000 );    
        $(this).switchClass( "col-md-3", "col-md-6", 1000 );

        }


      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your layout like this but changing the way it expands to just apply to the right side of the box and show the content just there.

Well, to do this you will need to divide the box in two sides: the options side (left) and the content side (right). You should then set the height for the content side as the same height of all options side and set `overflow-y: auto;`. Also, change the content side background color to the same as the option hovered. I think it is a good approach.